# Yii - renderpartial from module to root folder

Tags: yii, yii-modules

i am trying to render the view from module to project base view but it gives error.

I tried below combinations without any luck. It gives the error "DefaultController cannot find the requested view "appsMenu"."

```
echo $this->renderPartial("appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""),true, true);
echo $this->renderPartial("//appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("views/site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("views/site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("protected/views/site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("/protected/views/site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("views/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("/views/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("site/views/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("site/views/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("protected/views/site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("//protected/views/site/appsMenu",array("moduleName"=>""));
```

and tried with extensions too

```
echo $this->renderPartial("appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""),true, true);
echo $this->renderPartial("//appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("views/site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("views/site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("protected/views/site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("/protected/views/site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("views/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("/views/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("site/views/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("site/views/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("protected/views/site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
echo $this->renderPartial("//protected/views/site/appsMenu.php",array("moduleName"=>""));
```

I am in "Forms" module and trying to render a file "protected/views/site/appsMenu.php". Plz help me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `//`:

```
$this->renderPartial("//site/appsMenu");
```

This can be seen in the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getViewFile-detail)

> absolute view within the application: the view name starts with double slashes '//'. In this case, the view will be searched for under the application's view path. This syntax has been available since version 1.1.3.

Comment: simple and understandable

Answer (score 2):

This nasty little bit did the trick for me

```
$this->renderPartial('//../modules/MyMod/views/MyCon/MyView');
```

Using `//` to alias to `$root/protected/views` and then putting that `../` bit in there to get me to `$root/protected/views/../modules/$m/views/$c/$v` which really means `$root/protected/modules/$m/views/$c/$v`

Of course, put reasonable values in for the $X and/or MyXXX values above.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once('./protected/modules/MyMod/views/MyCon/MyView.php');
```

Use above line if you are not able to render file using yii